# Добавление элемента в односвязный список.Непонятные операции

Tags: c, структуры-данных, односвязный-список

Сначала создаю структуру

```
    struct LIST
{
    int field;
    struct LIST *pNext; 
};

    struct LIST* pHead;
инициализирую первый элемент 
struct LIST* init(int number)
{
    struct LIST *lst;
    lst = (struct LIST*)malloc(sizeof(struct LIST));
    lst->field = number;
    lst->pNext = NULL;
    return lst;
};



struct LIST* add(struct LIST* lst, int number)
{
    struct LIST * pNew;
    pNew = (struct LIST*)malloc(sizeof(struct LIST));
    pNew->field = number;


    pNew->pNext = lst->pNext; //2
    lst->pNext = pNew; //3
    return pNew;

}


int main()
{
    pHead = init(5);
    struct LIST* pTmp = add(pHead, 10);
}
```

Вопрос: как работает функция add , особенно непонятно  , что делается тут,что происходит с указателями и как понять вот такое *lst->pNext*
Почему обращение должно происходить через pNew и чем оно отличается от обращения с помощью lst?

```
pNew->pNext = lst->pNext; //2
        lst->pNext = pNew; //3
```

И можете , пожалуйста, объяснить , что делает это программа в целом ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не добавление, а вставка после элемента `lst`. Функция должна называться `insert`.

У объекта `lst` есть указатель на идущий за ним элемент списка. Функция вставляет после `lst` новый элемент `pNew`. Поэтому

```
lst->pNext = pNew;
```

но тот элемент, который раньше шел за `lst`, теперь будет идти за `pNew`. Поэтому

```
pNew->pNext = lst->pNext;
```

Эти два действия выполняются в обратном порядке, чтобы не затереть первоначальное значение `lst->pNext`.

> обращение ... через pNew и чем оно отличается от обращения с помощью lst

Это указатели на два разных объекта. Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите спросить.

Comment: а что вообще делает lst->pNext , как этот указатель составного типа взаимодействует с pNext ?Получается у каждого pNew или  lst свой собственный  pNext ?

Comment: @Elvin Да, у каждого свой собственный. Вы представляете смысл слов "односвязный список"?

Comment: c трудом , но видимо это цепочка , "вагончики" одинакого типа , связанных между собой указателями , и вроде бы это всё рекурсивно

Comment: @Elvin Да, у каждого вагончика есть указатель на следующий. У последнего вагончика значение этого указателя - `NULL`.